# $\widetilde{H}_k(S^n\setminus f(\mathbb{D}^m))=0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to prove the generalized Jordan Curve Theorem via homology theory. In order to do this I have to show that $\widetilde{H}_k(S^n\setminus f(\mathbb{D}^m))=0$ for all $k$, where $\mathbb{D}^m$ is the $m$-disk and $f$ is an embedding. I would prove this last claim by induction and by Mayer-Vietoris sequence, whitouth us the concept of limit. Are there ideas or references?

Comment: I know this question is very old, but this is Proposition 2B.1.(a) in Hatcher, which he proves without limits.